# Replace words in a string - Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string in Ruby:

```
sentence = "My name is Robert"
```

How can I replace any one word in this sentence easily without using complex code or a loop?

Comment: Replace in what way? Replace an arbitrary word (word #2), or a specific word (`my`)?

Comment: Thanks for your short, simple and useful question. it helped me out finding a solution to style hashtags in my view

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can try using this way :

```
sentence ["Robert"] = "Roger"
```

Then the sentence will become :

```
sentence = "My name is Roger" # Robert is replaced with Roger
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting.  I've never seen this method of replacement before.

Comment: Won't you get an error with this method if the original string doesn't contain the word you're trying to replace?

Comment: I'm also interested in @srcspider's question

Comment: Just make sure to resuce on `IndexError`. Otherwise for a word not part of the sentence will lead to: `string not matched (IndexError)`

Comment: That's really nice. Seems like Ruby is interrupting the string as a hash or array but changing the key instead the value. Could anyone tell this is a ordinary way of doing this?

Comment: Another problem with this method is that it only replaces the first instance of the string.

Comment: Another problem with this method is when you use this in with activerecord. `u = User.first; u.name["black"] = "blue"; u.save!` won't save the change..

Comment: This is interesting, but should definitely not be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Does this work without spaces?  I suspect Ruby is converting to an array based on space delimiters

Comment: A quick fix for not having to rescue from `IndexError` is to check for if the word exists on string, like so:
`string["Robert"] = "Roger" if string.include?("Robert")`

Answer (score 573):

```
sentence.sub! 'Robert', 'Joe'
```

Won't cause an exception if the replaced word isn't in the sentence (the `[]=` variant will).

### How to replace all instances?

The above replaces only the first instance of "Robert".

To replace all instances use `gsub`/`gsub!` (ie. "global substitution"):

```
sentence.gsub! 'Robert', 'Joe'
```

The above will replace all instances of Robert with Joe.

Comment: This seems to replace only the first instance, which is of course sometimes fine and sometimes not.

Comment: @JasonSwett updated the answer to cover how to replace all instances.

Comment: Just be careful when using `sub!` and `gsub!` on a string literals - the non-exclamation mark versions should be used instead. Strings literals will be immutable in Ruby 3 and this will raise an exception.

Comment: If you're looking to replace all occurrences with nothing (e.g. `""`) then you can also look at using `delete!( "Robert" )`.

Comment: Like @ItayGrudev mentions, be aware that `.sub!` mutates `sentence`. You should might want to use just `.sub` instead

Comment: Beware this will change "Robertino" to "Joeino", which is probably **not** want you want.

Answer (score 174):

If you're dealing with natural language text and need to replace a word, not just part of a string, you have to add a pinch of regular expressions to your gsub as a plain text substitution can lead to disastrous results:

```
'mislocated cat, vindicating'.gsub('cat', 'dog')
=> "mislodoged dog, vindidoging"
```

Regular expressions have word boundaries, such as `\b` which matches start or end of a word. Thus,

```
'mislocated cat, vindicating'.gsub(/\bcat\b/, 'dog')
=> "mislocated dog, vindicating"
```

In Ruby, unlike some other languages like Javascript, word boundaries are UTF-8-compatible, so you can use it for languages with non-Latin or extended Latin alphabets:

```
'сіль у кисіль, для весіль'.gsub(/\bсіль\b/, 'цукор')
=> "цукор у кисіль, для весіль"
```

Comment: Note that some languages don't even use spaces, so `\b` doesn't work in them, you would need to use morphological analyzers or stuff like that in those cases. Also, +1 for hilarious example.

Answer (score 51):

First, you don't declare the type in Ruby, so you don't need the first `string`.

To replace a word in string, you do: `sentence.gsub(/match/, "replacement")`.