# How to use Jekyll site.pages to generate sitemap.xml

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to use site.pages to automatically generate `sitemap.xml` in Jekyll (GitHub Pages), This is the `sitemap.xml` code I got:

```
---
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    {% for page in site.pages %}
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com{{ page.url | remove: 'index.html' }}</loc>
    </url>
    {% endfor %}
</urlset>
```

It's output is something similar to this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/samplepage.html</loc>
    <!--<loc>https://example.com/samplepage</loc>-->
  </url>
</urlset>
```

My goal is to generate a sitemap.xml without the trailing `.html` as in the commented line. I've tried `gsub` (I assumed Jekyll takes Ruby syntax: [Replace words in string - ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381499/replace-words-in-string-ruby)) but it seems either doesn't change anything or remove page.url completely.

I'd appreciate if anyone can

1. modify the Jekyll syntax so that it generates URLs without the trailing `.html`.
2. explain the syntax of `| remove: 'index.html'` (which removes the URL `https://example.com/index.html` from the generated `sitemap.xml`).

I'm very unfamiliar with Jekyll so apologies if the question seems trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll uses Liquid to [process templates](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/). The pipe syntax is a [Liquid filter](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#advanced-output-filters):

> Filters are simple methods. The first parameter is always the output of the left side of the filter. The return value of the filter will be the new left value when the next filter is run. When there are no more filters, the template will receive the resulting string.

`remove` is one of the [standard Liquid filters](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#standard-filters), so the Jekyll documentation does not list it.

---

If you have this file in your root folder, the page URL is straightforward:

```
samplepage.html    # https://example.com/samplepage.html
```

Instead, if you have:

```
samplepage/
    index.html     # https://example.com/samplepage/index.html
                   # https://example.com/samplepage/
```

The page URL ends up being the folder name, and the server will automatically serve the `index.html` file inside if you use the second link.

`site.pages` will give you the first link. As you have a filter that removes `index.html` from your paths, you end up with [extension-free URLs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/#named-folders-containing-index-html-files).

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Any file in Jekyll folder is generated with his extension, except if you use [permalink](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/).

If  you create a `sitemap.xml` file like this :

```
---
layout: null
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    {% for page in site.pages %}
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com{{ page.url | remove: 'index.html' }}</loc>
    </url>
    {% endfor %}
</urlset>
```

It will be generated as `sitemap.xml`.

You can also use [jekyll-sitemap](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap) wich is supported by github pages.