# How to remove first element of each element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I don't understand how to remove the first element of each word in an array of strings:

```
value = ["$6558.07", "$468.95", "$0.487526"]
```

and I want a array with:

```
value = ["6558.07", "468.95", "0.487526"]
```

I want to remove the `$` to convert this array into an array of float to compare values, etc.

I tried this:

```
value.each do | value |
    value.drop(1)
end
```

and that just removes the entire first value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace words in a string - Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381499/replace-words-in-a-string-ruby)

Comment: I think you didn't mean integer as those numbers have decimals too, which an integer can't hold

Comment: `"6558.07"`  is a _string_, not an integer. If you really wanted to have integers, you'd use [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-to_i), or [`to_f`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-to_f) for floats, [`to_d`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/String.html#method-i-to_d) for decimals etc.

Comment: For fun: `"$6558.07".reverse.to_f.to_s.reverse #=> "6558.07"`.

Comment: Your question deals with a piece of a problem you are working on. You might have found answers more helpful had you addressed a larger problem in your question. For one, having a separate step that converts an array of strings to another array of strings might not be the best approach in the larger problem. I say this as food for thought when posting questions in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby srtrings have a method which deletes a prefix:

```
value.map{|v| v.delete_prefix("$").to_f}
# => [6558.07, 468.95, 0.487526]
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. [String.delete_prefix](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix-21)

```
as @steenslag answer
```

> 2. [String#delete!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete)

```
values.each { |value| value.delete!('$') }
```

> 3. [String.gsub!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21)

```
values.each { |value| value.gsub!(/\$/, '') }
```

> 4. [String.replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-replace)

```
values.each { |value| value.replace(value[1..-1]) }
```

> 5. [String.slice!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-slice-21)

```
values.each { |value| value.slice!(0) }
```

> 6. [String.tr_s!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-tr_s-21)

```
values.each { |value| value.tr_s!('$', '') }
```

I would recommend you read the [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html) documentation.

Below is performance measurement with n = 10_000

```
               user       system     total       real
delete_prefix  0.086251   0.000000   0.086251 (  0.086255)
delete         0.096932   0.000000   0.096932 (  0.096925)
gsub!          0.141742   0.000000   0.141742 (  0.141744)
replace        0.077938   0.000000   0.077938 (  0.077942)
slice!         0.088919   0.000000   0.088919 (  0.088924)
tr_s!          0.084982   0.000000   0.084982 (  0.084988)
```